# Navigation view in Custom navigation drawer consist of Image view only

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have an app in which I am using navigation drawer and in this I am using navigation view . the code snippet is as follows

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer"
        />
```

and in menu i have this 
drawer.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/home"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/home"
            android:title="@string/home_string" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/offer"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/offer_"
            android:title="@string/offer_string" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/take"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/take"
            android:title="@string/take_string" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/share"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/share"
            android:title="@string/share_string" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/offer_status"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/my_status"
            android:title="@string/offer_status" />


        <item
            android:id="@+id/about_us"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/about_us"
            android:title="" />


    </group>
</menu>
```

this is working perfectly as the icons shows in left and corresponding text shows to right of image view in navigation drawer. 
but now I have to use the whole image with out text on the right to it as my new images contains the name in it also so there is no need to put the corresponding string to its right.

but if i just replace the images they got squeeze and I think because the new navigation menu has its limitation for image. and if I delete the string from item it gives me error as  item must have title string. so i put the empty string but it does the same I mean it squeeze the image.

So what should I do to show a complete image in a complete single row of navigation menu?? any help and idea please share

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid if you want anything custom with this menu, you have to implement the menu yourself instead of using `NavigationView`. I personally use a vertical `LinearLayout` inside a `ScrollView`, with a style applied to all TextViews and ColorFilters to tint the icons.

Here are some suggestions:

- Start with a `LinearLayout` inside a `ScrollView`, add an optional header followed by one `ImageView` for each section with the proper Drawable.
- Set a unique id on each `ImageView` representing a section.
- Set a single `View.OnClickListener` on each `ImageView` representing a section. When the view is clicked, use the view id to determine which section has been chosen by the user.

To color the current section Drawable with the primary color, use a code like this:

```
int primaryColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.color_primary);
sectionImageView.getDrawable().mutate().setColorFilter(primaryColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

(Call `setColorFilter(null)` to color it back to normal)

If you want more elaborate code, take a look at source code of "FOSDEM Companion":

- [main.xml](https://github.com/cbeyls/fosdem-companion-android/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/main.xml) (layout containing the custom menu in the drawer layout)
- [MainActivity.java](https://github.com/cbeyls/fosdem-companion-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/be/digitalia/fosdem/activities/MainActivity.java) (implements the menu logic)
- [AdapterLinearLayout.java](https://github.com/cbeyls/fosdem-companion-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/be/digitalia/fosdem/widgets/AdapterLinearLayout.java) (custom LinearLayout populated with the menu items using an Adapter)

Comment: so what should I do and how to put the background image instead of white in navigation view ?

Comment: You may use a LinearLayout which contains `ImageView`s for example.

Comment: Which part of code would help you? I can point you to a custom menu implementation I wrote, but it does not do exactly what you want because it uses TextViews as menu items and what you want is an ImageView.

Comment: so what should I then supposed to do can you please provide some code

Comment: or else isnt is possible to change your text views into imageview

Comment: thanks I'll try and would select as answer of this question if it helps , Right now I am so exhausted